# Where is the division in the house?

Tags: gospel-of-luke, demons

In Lk 11:14-23, a man is mute because of a demon. Jesus drives the demon out, and some in the crowd claim that he does this because he himself is in league with demons. He replies:
“Every kingdom divided against itself will be laid waste
and house will fall against house.
And if Satan is divided against himself,
how will his kingdom stand?
For you say that it is by Beelzebul that I drive out demons.
If I, then, drive out demons by Beelzebul,
by whom do your own people drive them out?"

Where is the contradiction between one party having the power of god, and the other party having the power of Satan? Is there necessarily only one way to drive out demons? How do we know? If Beelzebul has a stratagem that involves two steps, the first being to cause a man to become mute, and the second step being to have someone pretend to drive out the demon, how does that plan divide his house?

What are the ways that different Christian denominations look at this? Are there differences between denominations and contemporary schools of thought?